# Integer points in polyhedra

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, polyhedra

I kindly ask your expertise on the following point:

Let $P$ be an unbounded polyhedron of $R^d$ defined by linear inequalities as

$$P = \{x\in R^d : \ell_1 (x)< \alpha_1,\ \  \ell_2 (x)\leq \alpha_2, \ \ 
\ldots, \ell_t (x)\leq \alpha_t,  \}$$

where only the **first inequality is strict and the others are weaker**.

**My question is**: Does there exists some $\varepsilon >0$ such that the **closed polyhedron $P_\varepsilon$**

$$P_\varepsilon = \{x\in R^d : \ell_1 (x)\leq \alpha_1 - \varepsilon,\ \  \ell_2 (x)\leq \alpha_2, \ \ 
\ldots, \ell_t (x)\leq \alpha_t,  \}$$

contains the same integer points of $P$, i.e.

$$P_\varepsilon \cap Z^d = P \cap Z^d$$

For $d=1$ and for polytopes, this is true.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For a *bounded* polyhedron, the answer would be "yes"; for an unbounded one, not necessarily so.

Indeed, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there are integer points $(n,m)$ that satisfy $n-\sqrt2m>0$, but not $n-\sqrt2m\geqslant\varepsilon$. Ditto for any other irrational slope.

To make the answer always "yes", you need a stricter condition, like rational coefficients in $\ell_1 (x)$ or the boundedness of the polyhedron's face corresponding to it.

So it goes.

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thank you very much for your reply and for the indications. I see the point. In the case that the coefficients in $\ell_1$ are rational, in your opinion , is the proof of the claim straightforward? Thank you again

Comment: Yes, I expect it to be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thanks for your reply. Could you show a sketch of this proof? Thank you very much in advance for your expertise

Comment: Hi Ivan, would it be possible for you to show me a sketch of this proof or to give me some hint?

Comment: Say $q_1$ is the denominator of the coefficient at $x_1$ in $\ell_1$. Then there is only a finite number of different values (mod 1) for the first term in $\ell_1$, because they start repeating after $q_1$. Ditto for the second and other terms. Then the argument is the same as for the finite polyhedron: out of finitely many positive values, one is the minimum, and we may choose our $\varepsilon$ between it and zero.

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thank you very much for the proof

Comment: Hi Ivan, a question: Is your argument still valid in the case of $2$ or more strict inequalities? That is, starting from $P$ defined by $2$ or more inequalities of the form $\ell_i (x) < \alpha_i$, to get a closed polyhedron P' containing exactly the same integers of P?

Comment: I see no difference whatsoever. The answer is the same.